# How can automate sftp from machine B to machine C with machine A?

Tags: windows, automation, telnet

I have some files which need to be sftp from machine B ( linux ) to machine C. We need to start the task in machine A ( windows server 2003 ) and schedule this in Windows Scheduler. How can I do it?

I would do it interactively like this:

1. ftp the files from machine A to machine B.
2. telnet to machine B.
3. with the telnet, sftp from machine B to machine C, put the files from machine B to machine C.

How can I do this with a script in machine A which is a windows? I can't install any other software to help.

Comment: Your file is on A, and want to ftp it to B then from B sftp it to C?

Comment: Yes. This is the scenario because only B can connect C and the files is on A.

Comment: No. Unless there are no other option.

Comment: 've managed to make machine B available for a cron job. There is no such need to transfer the file. I probably have no time to verify each of the answer by all of you. I give the bounty to the highest vote answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned ftp, telnet, and sftp.  Those could be scripted via something like expect, or via some possibly complex script on A.  However, you might be able to use this unix trick to do it all from A.  You'll need to be able to ssh from A to B, and from B to C.  You'll need identity authentication setup, so that a password is not required for those connections.  (You could use agent forwarding of the identity on A for both connections.)  Then run something like this on A:

```
cat file-on-a | ssh B "ssh C 'cat > file-on-c'"
```

That will move the file from A to C, via B, without storing the file on B.

I have done this sort of thing on windows before using the ssh and cat that is part of Cygwin.  I don't know how well it would work with other windows tools...

**EDIT:** I should have said a word to two about how that command works.  The ssh program provides a *pipe* of sorts to move data back and forth between the local and remote machine.  Normally, this *pipe* is connected to a shell on the remote end and it serves the same purpose as telnet, except with better security.  However, this *pipe* can be used for anything.  The sftp utility uses that pipe to move files around.  The ssh command can take a command to execute on the remote system.  For example, `ssh B ls` would connect to B, run ls, and send the results back to you.  What the above command does is ssh to B, and ask B to run an ssh connecting to C.  That gives us a *pipe* from A, to B, to C.  Now, what to do at both ends?  The `cat` program reads files and writes them to standard out.  If no file names are given, it reads standard in.  The `cat file-on-a` read the file on the `A` machine and writes it to the `ssh` command.  The `cat > file-on-c` reads the data sent to it and the `> file-on-c` part (thanks to the shell) writes that to the file `file-on-c`.

Again, not sure if this is an option in your environment.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this is with 'scp', which typically comes in the same package as ssh and sftp, and which works just like 'cp' except that either or both paths can be remote:

```
scp user@machineA:/path/to/file user@machineB:/path/to/file
```

You need an ssh client which includes scp on the initiating machine, but you probably already have that.

Comment: It's a good reminder that both files can be remote, but the issue was that A had to initiate the transfer, and A does not have direct access to C (only B can access C).  Still, good reminder about scp.

Comment: Newer versions of `scp` have a `-3` option: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=scp&sektion=1

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into something like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) before it gets too late.  Using message queuing and remote scripts will assist in ensuring that tasks like these are completed correctly.

I know that this is not the answer that you were looking for, as it will require much more than a simple script, but using messaging can drastically decrease cross-platform administration over time.

If you really need to perform an action as described then you can use [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9900318/908471), but using blank keys is against best security practice.  An alternative would be a simple drop directory on B, which a script on B monitors, that is synced to C (either through ftp/sftp/rsync or even a remote mount) - again requiring a script on B.

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to be using a Windows intermediary between two Linux machines, the most idiomatic recommendation is for you to explore [SSHFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) for [Windows systems](http://dokan-dev.net/en/).

Your ideal case, if maintaining a pipeline between machines A and C is desirable in a Windows environment, is to be able to connect to both the pickup point (on A) and drop point (on C) and just write some [Batch automation](http://lifehacker.com/5669762/automate-just-about-anything-on-your-windows-pc-no-coding-required) to send files automatically. This isn't resilient to failures, mind you (you'll need to establish some sort of reconnection protocol), but it has the added benefit of being able to do it in your GUI when things go wrong or when you pass this system on to someone else.

Otherwise, if this is a quick job that can tolerably be run from shell, [Rob is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9900318/517815). It can be done, tersely and correctly, with simple pipe-stapling.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that only B can connect to C and you want to get files from A to C, I would suggest using SSH tunnel from B to C.
This way you could gain access from A to C through B.

From box B make ssh tunnel to box C:

```
ssh box-c.com -gL 3025:localhost:22
```

Then from box A connect to box C sftp by connecting to:

box-b.com:3025

To automate making the tunnel and keep it alive no matter what happens, I suggest using autossh - http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/ (comes with most Linux distributions).

If you want to block others from accessing box-b.com:3025, use box B firewall to allow connections to that port only from box A.

I sometimes get in similar situation and this is the easiest solution I have found.